# MATLAB: Combining LaTeX characters with data formatting in axes title

Tags: matlab, latex

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way for me to combine symbols via the TeX interpreter and data inputs into a single string for an axes title.

For example, my current code goes something like this:

```
figure
axHandle = axes;
appleTrees = 4;
s = sprintf( ...
    'Apples vs Acres\nNumber of Apples Trees $\alpha = %2.0f$', appleTrees);
title(axHandle,s,'Interpreter','LaTeX')
```

I understand this doesn't work, but I think it conveys what I am trying to do.

sprintf causes the following message:

```
Warning: Control Character '\l' is not valid. 
See 'doc sprintf' for control characters valid in the format string.
```

I can ditch sprintf and go simply quotes, but then I lose the data formatting / text formatting capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash `\` is a special character when formatting strings for certain functions in Matlab. `sprintf` is one of those. To write a backslash, use `\\` instead. [Here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z6xa) is a list of other special characters and how they can be written.

In your case, use the following lines:

```
s = sprintf( ...
    'Apples vs Acres\nNumber of Apples Trees $\\alpha = %2.0f$', appleTrees);
```

Comment: Nice you beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: Thanks for you help!  Could you also explain to me how I could center the resulting title text?

Comment: Try using two boxes like this: `\\makebox[10in][c]{Apples vs Acres}\n\\makebox[10in][c]{Number of Apples Trees $\\alpha = %2.0f$}`